# How can I do a Monitor.Wait with processing message queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, monitor

I'm using .NET 4.0 (no async).

I'm looking for a combination of [Monitor.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.monitor.wait(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx). I've browse object explorer but I can't find one.

**Does it exists ? If not, what is the best way to implement it ?**

I've still tried nothing because what I have in mind is very dirty. Something like this :

```
while (!(timeOutHasBeenReached || aLockHasBeenAcquired))
{
    Application.DoEvents() ; 
}
```

To avoid XY problem, let me introduce the final goal (relates to unit testing) :

```
using (ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ApplicationContext()) 
{
    using (Control control = new Control() { Visible = true } )
    {
        // control will do something across the web 
        // When the control has done it, it will raise an event invoking applicationContext.Exit() 
        // As a web connection is not always timing trustfull I'd like 
        // to specify a timeout (or eventually abort it with a Monitor.Pulse)

        Application.Run(applicationContext);         
    }
}
```

Control is a Winform component which I can't modify and I don't want to do `Thread.Abort` .

Comment: Application.DoEvents() is commonly (and many times wrongly) used for "avoiding" multi-threading. So what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @yms : I made an edit

Comment: Can't you abort by doing `control.Invoke(() => Application.Exit());`? Or just `control.Close();` or Dispose.

Comment: @usr : yes I can do it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you abort by doing `control.Invoke(() => Application.Exit());`? Or just `control.Close();` or `Dispose`.

Comment: I will do it with that. The real issue was that I was stucked with the sync way.